# Changing the title of an old question

Tags: discussion, moderation, title

Here the OP:

[Mapping Over a new Array() without populating it returns an empty array. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317698/mapping-over-a-new-array-without-populating-it-returns-an-empty-array-why?noredirect=1#comment81587005_47317698)

Didn't find this answer:

[JavaScript "new Array(n)" and "Array.prototype.map" weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501581/javascript-new-arrayn-and-array-prototype-map-weirdness)

Because of the title, as he said, may be better.

I have never changed the title of a popular question. Should I do it? Which title might be better?

Comment: Do *you* think that it's a bad title?  What do you think would be better?  What don't you like about the title, what do you think needs to be in a new title that isn't in that one?

Comment: The OP's title doesn't actually reflect the contents of the more popular question. They aren't really very good duplicates. I would say that both questions should be closed as duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371449/229044, if anything